# New Mac Mini (late 2014) sound input - says "No input devices found"

Tags: audio, mac-mini

I have just bought a new Mac Mini Late 2014. I noticed that the System Preferences > Sound says that there is no sound input device. This is causing me lots of problems in the app I'm developing in XCode.

My older 2012 Mac Mini shows an "Audio line-in port" and my app works.

Is there something wrong with my new Mac Mini? How can I get it to recognise the input port?

[image: No input devices found]

Comment: More info. When I plug a microphone in it is recognised and shows up on this screen, and my game works. On a Mac Mini 2012 I don't need to plug in a microphone and "No input devices found" is never displayed.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

Resetting the SMC and PRAM for Mac Pro, Intel-based iMac, Intel-based Mac mini, or Intel-based Xserve

• Shut down the computer.
• Unplug the computer's power cord.
• Wait fifteen seconds.
• Attach the computer's power cord.
• Locate the following keys on the keyboard: Command, Option, P, and R. You will need them in next step
• Wait five seconds, then press the power button to turn on the computer.
• Press and hold the Command-Option-P-R keys before the gray screen appears.
• Hold the keys down until the computer restarts.
• Release the keys.

Read more: http://www.justanswer.com/mac-computers/65d0r-mac-osx-no-sound-no-input-output-devices-found.html#ixzz3XNRpChvF